# How to ask Firefox to suggest a password when filling out registration form on the web?

Tags: firefox, passwords, password-management, password-generation

I am familiar with Safari on my Mac. Safari usually can recognize a registration form prompting for a new password. In such case, Safari automatically offers to generate a new random password.

Does Firefox 71 offer such a feature? I have somehow managed to save passwords in Firefox. But Firefox never offers to generate a password.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Firefox never offers to generate a password

You need to right click in a password field (Firefox 70+):

> Firefox 70 includes a new ‘securely generated password’ option that
>   works in HTML password fields.
>
> To use it, users simply right click in an empty password box on a
>   sign-up page or register form, then select the Fill Password > Use a
>   Securely Generated Password option.

Source [Firefox 70 is Here with New Logo, Secure Password Generator + More - OMG! Ubuntu!](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/10/firefox-70-new-logo-download)

[image: Screenshot of using context menu in a Password field to generate a random password]

Comment: Firefox definitely offers to generate passwords when clicking in some password fields for me; [this is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roXoP.png). Clicking the suggested password in the popup saves the newly generated password into Firefox's password store. If you want to try it, one place where it does consistently come up is the [Xenforo community forum](https://xenforo.com/community/), click the "register" link at the top and click on the password field.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution is using the free
[LastPass](https://www.lastpass.com/).

It will not only suggest an uncrackable password, but will also remember it for all
browsers, so it is always available and secure.

EDIT: I now recommend the free
[Bitwarden](https://bitwarden.com/),
as the free LastPass version has become too limited.

Comment: Or something open source, like keepass or bitwarden.

Comment: I've never come across Bitwarden before but KeePass is ancient, I migrated from it to LastPass and never looked back. It may not be open-source, but it's free, fully-featured and modern.

Comment: @Hashim I have no idea how old Keepass is, but it works completely fine on even my very new (2019) computers. What, specifically, is wrong with it? Just being old isn't a problem.

Comment: @john01dav: Old here means less features and no integration with newer OS such as smartphones or newer browsers.

Comment: @harrymc There is an Android Keepass app that works quite well. I use it frequently. Additionally, the Keepass desktop application auto-types username and password into not just any browser but any program, on any OS. As such, it has plenty of integration with newer OS's. This leaves your claim about missing features. What features, exactly, are missing?

Comment: @john01dav: LastPass is cloud-based while KeePass is not. For more detailed feature comparison, see for example [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/240255/password-managers-compared-lastpass-vs-keepass-vs-dashlane-vs-1password/).

Comment: Are you affiliated?

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski: ????

Answer (score 4):

Firefox is able to do this. Under **Preferences** > **Privacy and Security** > **Logins and Passwords** it can be enabled. The option is Suggest and generate strong passwords.

[image: Logins and Password]

For further reading, this is the ticket tracking the feature in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1565407

The feature requires password fields to have the attribute `autocomplete="new-password"` for it to work (as of now).

Comment: Unfortunately, that option does not actually work. I tried a few sites, including creating an account on Google.com. I'll up-vote now as I presume the feature will get fixed eventually. For now, I suggest to other readers that they context-click as shown in the [other Answer](https://superuser.com/a/1508444/212610).