# How to make Firefox generate a secure password outside a password field?

Tags: firefox, password-generation

I am familiar with getting Firefox to generate a secure password when it detects a password field in a form (as per the answer to [How to ask Firefox to suggest a password when filling out registration form on the web?](https://superuser.com/q/1508442/549628))  But how can I get Firefox to produce a similar random password **in an arbitrary text field, or directly in the Firefox Lockwise page** (`about:logins`) rather than on a specific web page?

It looks like the Lockwise page will let me enter a new login for a random web page, but doesn't seem to prompt to suggest a password for it.

I want to do this to a) create secure passwords for sites on which Firefox doesn't correctly detect the password entry field; and b) get Firefox to remember a password that I set by copying and pasting into some other system, e.g. via SSH.

Comment: Probably the best thing is to complain at the webmasters to fix their authentication forms. Other wise (s suggested already) use an external program like KeePass to generate and manage the passwords.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the "Save my Password" add-on to address this general scenario.  It injects a synthetic password entry form on top of a web page.  Firefox sees the form as it would a "real" login page.  You can then enter/generate credentials using that form, and Firefox will prompt to save them.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-my-password/